# How to trigger 2nd stage automatically after execution of 1st stage even if 1st stage is partially succeeded?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have Stage 1 and Stage 2 in Azure Pipeline. Stage 2 should be executed after the execution of stage 1. I have set up all the variables for triggering stage 2 post stage 1 but it does not trigger if there are any failures in stage 1. It only triggers automatically if stage 1 passes successfully. I have also set the control options variables where condition for `succeededOrFailed()` is mentioned, but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As far I udnderstood you want to have two stages when second stage always run even if first twill fail. I achieve this with:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - bash: echo "Hello world stage A first job"
    - pwsh: throw "This is an error."

# stage B runs if A fails
- stage: B
  condition: always()
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - bash: echo "Hello world stage B first job"
```

I added in first stage throw to fail this stage. And this is what I got:

[image: Stage view]